# Approximately how long should it take to delete 10m records from an MySQL InnoDB table with 30m records?

Tags: mysql

I am deleting approximately 1/3 of the records in a table using the query:

```
DELETE FROM `abc` LIMIT 10680000;
```

The query appears in the processlist with the state "updating". There are 30m records in total. The table has 5 columns and two indexes, and when dumped to SQL the file about 9GB.

This is the only database and table in MySQL.

This is running on a machine with 2GB of memory, a 3 GHz quad-core processor and a fast SAS disk. MySQL is not performing any reads or writes other than this `DELETE` operation. No other "heavy" processes are running on the machine.

This query has been running for more than 2 hours -- how long can I expect it to take?

Thanks for the help! I'm pretty new to MySQL, so any tidbits about what's happening "under the hood" while running this query are definitely appreciated.

Let me know if I can provide any other information that would be pertinent.

**Update:** I just ran a `COUNT(*)`, and in 2 hours, it's only deleted 200k records. I think I'm going to take Joe Enos' advice and see how well inserting the data into a new table and dropping the previous table performs.

**Update 2:** Sorry, I actually *misread* the number. In 2 hours, it's not deleted **anything**. I'm confused. Any suggestions?

**Update 3:** I ended up using `mysqldump` with `--where "true LIMIT 10680000,31622302"` and then importing the data into a new table. I then deleted the old table and renamed the new one. This took just over half an hour.

Comment: Are you aware that LIMIT without ORDER BY means that it can choose any 10 million records to delete?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip. I simply want to delete 1/3 of the records so that's okay.

Will it be the same set of records as if I'd simply queried `SELECT * FROM abc LIMIT 10680000;`? That query consistently returned the same set of records. Do tables have a "natural order"?

Comment: Are there any FK's to the PK on the table being deleted? Those can slow down delete performance since the DB must check to make sure those aren't violated as part of the delete.

Comment: btreat: No, none. There aren't any other tables in the database -- just the one. Thanks for the tip though, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: No, tables have no defined natural order. Of course, the data does have some ordering on the disk, which is why you consistently get the same records. This order may be changed though, whenever the database feels like it, so it can't be relied upon.

Comment: Update: I just ran a COUNT(*), and in 2 hours, it's only deleted 200k records.

Comment: Update 2: Sorry, I actually *misread* the number. In 2 hours, it's not deleted **anything**. I'm confused. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by running a COUNT(\*)? If you mean SELECT COUNT(\*) blabla..., that doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Bart: No no, I ran that after aborting the `DELETE` query, and discovered that nothing had been deleted. (I'm assuming this is because the query occurs in a transaction, or similar?)

Comment: If you abort the query during a transaction, it will rollback, so nothing will get modified.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deleting so many rows in a single transaction.  MySQL with InnoDB will lock the indexes to do the updates and prevent other inserts into the table.  For a particular app instance, we found deleting 10k at a time was a good balance.  This app tends to hold 200-500M total rows in a table with deletes ranging from 1-12M per associated record in another table. One last thing to consider, if the index or table is larger than available memory, you're doing disk based updates.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this would be any better, but it might be worth thinking about doing the following:
Create a new table and insert 2/3 of the original table into the new one.
Drop the original table.
Rename the new table to the original table's name.

This would prevent the log file from having all the deletes, but I don't know if inserting 20m records is faster than deleting 10m.

Comment: Great point -- that might be quite a lot faster! The entire database was inserted from the SQL file in less than 30 minutes.

What's the best way to get a dump of the data restricted to `LIMIT 10680000,31622302`?

Comment: I'm not a MySql guy, but if MySql is anything like other DB providers, then there should be a SELECT INTO syntax where you can select the records you want to keep, and it will automatically insert, rather than a dump and separate insert.  Assuming this exists, then you can just write a SELECT statement of what you want, with "INTO NEW_TABLE_NAME" in the query, and it does the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You should post the table definition.
Also, to know why is it taking to much time, try to enable the profile mode on the delete request via :

```
SET profiling=1; 
DELETE FROM abc LIMIT 10680000;
SET profiling=0;
SHOW PROFILES;
SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY X; (X is the ID of your query shown in SHOW PROFILES)
```

and post what it returns (But I think the query must end to return the profiling data)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Also, I think you'll get more responses on ServerFault ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you run this query, the InnoDB log file for the database is used to record all the details of the rows that are deleted - and if this log file isn't large enough from the outset it'll be auto-extended as and when necessary (if configured to do so) - I'm not familiar with the specifics but I expect this auto-extension is not blindingly fast.  2 hours does seem like a long time - but doesn't surprise me if the log file is growing as the query is running.

Is the table from which the records are being deleted on the end of a foreign key (i.e. does another table reference it through a FK constraint)?

Comment: No, there are no other tables in the database -- just the one.

Comment: how will things change if another table references it through a FK constraint?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your query ended by now ... :) but from what I've seen, LIMIT with large numbers (and I never tried this kind of numbers) is very slow. I would try something based on the pk like

```
DELETE FROM abc WHERE abc_pk < 10680000;
```